# Password lock site except for certain routes running nginx

Tags: nginx, .htpasswd

We have a server we don't want Google to index or anyone else to get access to unless they have a password.

How can I directory lock the entire server except for very specific routes used by external scanning services?

For instance, example.com/test should output a response from the framework without blocking but any other URL should ask for a password to get any content response.

I know how to do this with Apache using `.htpasswd`, but I need to be able to do it on nginx while whitelisting a specific route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will enable /test/ to respond without needing any authentication and every other request will need authentication.

```
server {

  auth_basic      "Administrator Login";
  auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/static/.htpasswd;

  location /test/ {
    auth_basic off;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
server {
    ...
    auth_basic "Enter password";
    auth_basic_user_file path/to/htpasswd;

    location /test/ {
        auth_basic off;
    }
}
```